# At what stage do a browser auto-fix html code? Odd behaviour regarding auto-fix function

Tags: html, browser

**NOTE:** I am aware that the following code is incorrect and I know exactly how to fix it, I am just taking it as an example to help me learn more about browsers.

This question is about the common function of most modern browser, auto-correcting invalid html code such as

```
<a href="xxx" onClick="yyy()"/>
```

into

```
<a href="xxx" onclick="yyy()"/>
```

---

First of all, due to some constraint I can not show the actual code I have but I'll try my best to make some similar example for it.

I have a certain piece of html [I'll call this **CASE 1**]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html, charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="xxx" onClick="yyy()"/>
</body>
</test>
```

where the test tag will be replace with proper html tab BEFORE it is sent out from the server. the tag will be replaced by...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:lang="en-EN">

</html>
```

turns out when it reaches the browser, the onClick attribute is still with a capital C which is not the correct syntax. I checked the html source with the in-browser "show source" function and the test tag were correctly replaced by proper html tags. I have also tried to wget and the source looks the same as browser, with proper html tags.

**CASE 2**

I then decided to skip the replace process and put the tags in my html file directly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:lang="en-EN">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html, charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="xxx" onClick="yyy()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

this time, although the source I check forom browser and wget both have a capital C for onClick, and is exactly the same as CASE 1, it was auto-corrected by the browser into onclick when it's finally displayed to me.

**MY QUESTION:**

so if the source of both case is exactly the same (as far as I know), why do case 1 did not get auto-correct?

---

UPDATE:
I've made sure that the response header's content type is correctly set but it still seems to be "not working" (when my test tag is in use, the html will not get auto-correct @ browser)

```
[]$ curl -i "http://fakeurl.com/test"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 May 2014 08:40:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=2407DAA766B35B1DE848241137BF00D4; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=B71F83B1C77F8986FE03B61594E5878B; Path=/
Content-Length: 6325
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:lang="en-EN">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html, charset=utf-8" />
    (the rest is the same as example)
```

Comment: cURL is never going to normalise the HTML, for that matter if you look at the *source* in a browser, no browser will either. You are looking at the DOM inspector which shows you a normalised serialization of the DOM.

Comment: yeah, I am aware of the normalisation is carried out by the browser, the only reason I am showing curl is to show the content type. I verified it that it indeed is "not working" in a browser after I made sure he content tpye seems to be text/html (shown in curl).

Answer (score 2):

XML (and thus XHTML) has case sensitive tag and attributes names. HTML does not.

Browsers will normalise tag and attribute names to lower case equivalents for documents served with a `text/html` Content-Type but will nor for documents served with an `application/xhtml+xml` Content-Type.

Comment: thanks for the info, i'll take a deeper look in it. It's totally my fault that I couldn't show the code but I actually have specify content type = text/html under both case, I've updated the question.

Comment: Content-Type is determined by HTTP headers, not by `<meta>` tags. A meta tag that specifies a content-type serves no purpose other then to specify a character encoding.

Comment: while I attempt to fiddle with headers, can I ask then why do CASE 2 has auto-correct? It seems to me you might have point out some flaw in my code, but it still doesn't explain the difference between CASE 1 and 2? if you explaination is indeed the root cause, then surely BOTH case will not get auto-correct?

Comment: Presumably the different files are getting different content-types. There's no other reason, that I'm aware of, for the code to be normalised in one instance but not the other.

Comment: thanks for the tip @Quentin, I've learnt a bit more about the difference between request header and meta tag during my leave. I've also updated my question, I've set the content type correctly (i think), but it's still the same old case.

Comment: I assume that any switch to send an XHTML content-type will be conditional based on either the browser's user agent or the accept headers. (For historical reasons that mostly involve many browsers being awful at XHTML but fine with treating XHTML like invalid HTML). The different won't show up with cURL because the headers in the request will be different.